# Rails submit button not work in firefox and edge but work in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firefox

In my rails application, I have a submit button

```
<%= button_tag (type: 'submit', id:'logo-submit' , class: "btn btn-
       transparent", style:'') do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
<% end %>
```

It works fine in Chrome but doesn't work in firefox.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: it also works in firefox. possibly you've attached a listener function to this button and this one causes problems. plz also share them.

Comment: Have you checked firefox console for any errors

Comment: It should work, make sure you have used well syntax of `JS` or `jQuery` for this button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Error is not in the button_tag. In this button styles

```
#logo-submit{

left:300px;
top:5px;
background-color:transparent;

}
```

using

```
display: block;
```

now application work fine

Comment: Can you be more detailed about what the problem was and how you fixed it.